# Request-Promise: do promise cache the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using [Request-Promise](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request-promise)  (*See code below*).

**Question:** *If I cache a promise, do it cache the result or each time ask a new one?*

**Example:**

```
var cachedPromise = getTokenPromise();
cachedPromise.then(function(authorizationToken1) {
   //...
});
cachedPromise.then(function(authorizationToken2) {
   //...
});
//QUESTION: Is right that authorizationToken1 equals authorizationToken2
```

***getTokenPromise() function:***

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var rp = require('request-promise'); 

/**
 * Returns an authorization token promise
 */ 
function getTokenPromise() {
    var requestOpts = {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        uri: 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13',
        method: 'POST',
        body: querystring.stringify({
            'client_id': 'Subtitles',
            'client_secret': 'Xv.............................s=',
            'scope': 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        })
    };
    return rp(requestOpts);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I cache a promise, do it cache the result

A promise can only have a single result (in case it doesn't get rejected). It therefore can also be only resolved only once - and must not change its state thereafter.

In fact, the [promise spec](http://promisesaplus.com/) states

> 2. 1. 2. When fulfilled, a promise:
>
>          - must not transition to any other state.
>          - must have **a value**, which **must not change**.

> or each time ask a new one?

No. `getTokenPromise()` is the call that asks for the token, and it is executed only once. `cachedPromise` only *represents the result*, not an action. The action itself would have been executed even if you didn't add a callback via `.then()`.