# Handling of Promise when trying to cache something

Tags: javascript, html, angular, async-await, promise

I have a third party Angular library as a dependency, which is doing http requests (superagent), so I can't intercept it. I want to cache the values I get, because I have a list with sometimes similar information in the UI and I don't need to always make the same request.

So here is my code to receive a user from the API:

```
getUser(userId: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const cached = this.cacheService.get(userId);
        if (cached) {
          resolve(cached);
        } else {
        let user = await this.THIRDPARTYAPI.getUser(userId);
        this.cacheService.put(user.id, user);
        resolve(user);
      }
  });}
```

(The async/await is just my latest try).

This gets used in the following part

```
     data.forEach((row: any) => {
       this.getUser(row.userId).then((user: any)=>{
      //do something
      });
```

However it will always trigger the THIRDPARTYAPI.getUser(userId) method, so it will put the value inside my cache service, after it's already to late and the values have already been check. It doesn't really run the forEach entirely one after the other, and I am confused, how I could realise this.

Comment: Cache _the promise_.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62595659/3001761.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709987/caching-javascript-promise-results

Comment: Why are you wrapping in a new Promise on line 2? Keep the async/await. Regardless, what does the cacheService.get look like? I think the issue may be inside of there.

Comment: Also, with JS, make sure you are comparing the same data type. "3" !== 3. I wonder if this is your problem within the cacheService.get

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem isn't really in the `getUser()` method but how you're consuming it inside the `forEach()`.

I assume that the reason why you're trying to cache the responses for each `userId` is because they show up multiple times inside `data`.

If you're calling `getUser()` inside the `forEach()` you should keep in mind that each iteration will **not** wait until they're finished. This means that for each item in `data` you would have immediately called `getUser()`. Since this method is called way too quickly, your `cacheService` will always miss.

---

One way to solve this could be to use `await` inside a `for...of` block as such:

```js
for (const row of data) {
  const result = await this.getUser(row.userId)
  // do something with result
}
```

This would execute each request sequentially.

---

Another way could be to filter unique rows based on the `row.userId` property, call `getUser()` on them and then do your `forEach()` loop. At that point, all the user objects should have been cached an your `forEach()` would always hit the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might cache the promise:

```js
getUser(userId: number): Promise<any> | any {
  const cached = this.cacheService.get(userId);
  if (cached) return cached;
  
  const userPromise = this.THIRDPARTYAPI.getUser(userId);
  this.cacheService.put(user.id, userPromise);

  // Optional if you want the cache to eventually contain users and not just promises.
  userPromise.then(user => cacheService.put(user.id, user));
  
  return userPromise;
}
```

As an aside, your original code is a very bad use of `new Promise()` and it will ignore errors. This is how your original code should have looked like for your future reference:

```js
async getUser(userId: number): Promise<any> {

   const cached = this.cacheService.get(userId);
   if (cached) return cached;

   const user = await this.THIRDPARTYAPI.getUser(userId);
   this.cacheService.put(user.id, user);
   return user;
}
```

In most cases `new Promise()` is a red flag that something bad is about to happen.

Comment: "*Optional if you want the cache to eventually contain users and not just promises*" - but then you cannot use `return cached` any longer, it would need to become `return Promise.resolve(cached)`.

Comment: I could easily be mistaken, but once a promise has been resolved, its done and you can't read from that value again. Whereas if you cache the result, you can read the result as much as you want. Unlike observables, you can read while the stream is open, and if its a BehaviorSubject you can read the current value.

Comment: @Esaith "*you can't read from that value again*" - yes you're mistaken :-) You can *always* read from a promise, even multiple times, both before and after it is resolved, and are guaranteed to (eventually) get the same result every time. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26023000/1048572

Comment: Yes, I did a bit more research and found this. It's just that it will only return whatever the first value is, but if I'm calling a promise I'd be expecting the latest value, not the first value. With the context of thinking we are dealing with a cache, I guess this is fine but if someone mislabels it I think I'd be confused on why the latest value is not getting pulled.

Comment: @Esaith Being confused about how promises work doesn't make this a bad solution. Perhaps you could use a different function name that better suggests that this uses a cache, but i don't see how this has any bearing on the question. This is a pretty standard pattern.

Comment: @Bergi updated the return type.

Comment: @Esaith A promise represents a **single** (asynchronous) result. It can only resolve once,  there are no multiple ("first", "latest") values. A promise cannot be "called", it is not a function.

Comment: @Evert You're right that it's not a wrong approach, but different way I tend do it. I tend to call a promise once, convert the object into an entity, then save that entity. This is what OP is doing. Otherwise, saving the promise requires me to convert the object to entity on every single call to the get(). I don't see the benefit. On simple entities you can skip the assigning, but if the entity has methods this is a requirement.

Comment: @Bergi I understand a promise is an object but using .then is a function call so is await. You must use either of these functions to get the result. I also understand a promise can return only once. await GetValue() and await GetValue() are two calls that call twice, and depending how far between they are called could return different results whereas const value = GetValue(), await value and await value, will always return the same result. I suppose the end result is, you never know the skill level of other devs you're working with. Cursory glance at these promises could cause confusion.

Comment: @Esaith "*saving the promise requires me to convert the object to entity on every single call to the `get()`*" - no, just save the promise for the converted entity. "*using .then is a function call*" - so what? Not storing the promise simply doesn't work if you got multiple calls to `getUser()`, like the OP.

Comment: @Esaith storing the process instead of the entity is actually less total work, because fewer promises are created. Regardless, 'This would confuse me' is a valid criticism to me, although I think you're probably in a small group. It's a pretty standard way to solve this and now you've seen this, you'll probably see it in other places.

Comment: @Evert Like any other bug that takes more than a few hours to resolve, new info like this won't be forgotten. Thanks and Bergi